# Adding filter operators for Angular Formly generated fields

Tags: angular-formly

I need to add filter operators such as like "<", ">", "=", "like" before my field input.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

I only need the operator value - my applications back-end will do the rest.

Something like this perhaps

```
{age:{value:25,filterOperator:"<"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to follow something like [this example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/advanced-layout-flex) that allows you to put two fields next to each other using flexbox. Or if you have to use some other grid system, you might look at the [bootstrap version](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/bootstrap-specific/advanced-layout)